# Calculating a month in julian counting (year starts with march) with basic arithmetic only

Tags: math, julian-date

I am trying to convert an integer representing a month (1=january, 2=february.. 12=december) to an integer representing that month but in julian counting (1=march, 2=april.. 12=february). However I can only use integers and basic arithmetic (-,+,/,* and modulo).

for example:

```
month->julianMonth  
1->11  
2->12   
3->1   
4->2   
5->3  
...
```

The closest I get is with

```
julianMonth=(month+10)%12
```

which returns every value right but february.

Comment: `%12` will return the sequence `0,1,...,11,0,1,...` so throw in a `+1` at the right place in your calculation.

Comment: ... probably rewrite the *rhs* to `(month+9)%12+1` (untested)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it:

```
julianMonth=(month+9)%12+1
```

Comment: It would be polite to reference High Performance Mark, if that's where you got the answer.